# The conversion of block data into the 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I only a beginner in python, so I ask this question. I have a file with data like as

```
0.00 0.00    0.00  0.00   0.00 1.20
0.00 0.00    0.02  7.00   0.00 3.20

1.00 0.00    4.00  5.00   0.00 3.20
2.00 3.00    0.02  0.00   0.00 4.20
```

……….

I need to convert this data to the array A[i,j,k]. The i is a index of one block with four numbers. The increasing is from the left to the right. In this case i=0,1,2,3,4,5. The j is index of string. In this case j=0,1. The k index is column in one block, k=0,1. For more clarification, A[1,1,1]=7.00. How can I do it using numpy or scipy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `numpy.reshape` and `swapaxes`:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  1.2 ],
                [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.02,  7.  ,  0.  ,  3.2 ],
                [ 1.  ,  0.  ,  4.  ,  5.  ,  0.  ,  3.2 ],
                [ 2.  ,  3.  ,  0.02,  0.  ,  0.  ,  4.2 ]])

arr.reshape(-1,2,3,2).swapaxes(2,1).reshape(-1,2,2)    
#array([[[ 0.  ,  0.  ],
#        [ 0.  ,  0.  ]],

#       [[ 0.  ,  0.  ],
#        [ 0.02,  7.  ]],

#       [[ 0.  ,  1.2 ],
#        [ 0.  ,  3.2 ]],

#       [[ 1.  ,  0.  ],
#        [ 2.  ,  3.  ]],

#       [[ 4.  ,  5.  ],
#        [ 0.02,  0.  ]],

#       [[ 0.  ,  3.2 ],
#        [ 0.  ,  4.2 ]]])
```

---

To be more programmatic:

```
# target array shape
t_shape = (6, 2, 2)
assert arr.shape[1]%t_shape[2] == 0
arr.reshape(-1, t_shape[1], arr.shape[1]/t_shape[2], t_shape[2]).swapaxes(2,1).reshape(t_shape)
```

---

To load string as array:

```
from io import BytesIO  # for python 2
# from io import StringIO for python 3
arr = np.genfromtxt(BytesIO("""0.00 0.00    0.00  0.00   0.00 1.20
0.00 0.00    0.02  7.00   0.00 3.20
1.00 0.00    4.00  5.00   0.00 3.20
2.00 3.00    0.02  0.00   0.00 4.20"""))
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try! My real task is connected with the big table (more than 108 block and 40 numbers in one blocks. I will response if it works!

Comment: I have big tables. In my case i=0..107, j=0..2, k=0..37. As I understood I need to insert comma myself (manually)?

Comment: I added a programmatic solution to start with target shape. so In your case `t_shape = (108, 3, 38)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try now and check with my data. After it I mark your answer!

Comment: Sorry, maybe it is a stupid question, but I don’t understand. Originally I have only the set of values in blocks without comma and bracket, but with the blank lines… I can understand how to tern the final result from the intermediate list. But how can I convert the initial set of numbers into the list (or array) with numbers? I note again in my case I have (108,3, 38,)…
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `np.loadtext` or `np.genfromtext` to read the file in?

Comment: No, you deleted answer about it before I started to copy.)

Comment: If you have a text file, just do `arr = np.loadtxt("myfile.txt")` or `arr = np.genfromtxt("myfile.txt")`;

Comment: Now I understood and can see the initial array. I think that I solve it using your code my task! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it helps !